MKDocs - Global Variables Possible Within Page?
Regarding MKDocs, is it possible to set a global macro or variable from within a page?  My intent is to have a start page with a drop down menu.  The global variables would be set based on the user's selection and then referenced by other pages.
{% set myvar = 'some-value' %}   - this is only referable from the local page.
